# Does every power of two arise as the difference of two primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> For each $n\in\mathbb N$ there are primes $q<p$ with $p-q=2^n$.

Verified for $n\leq 26$:

```
 n        p  q
 0        3  2
 1        5  3
 2        7  3
 3       11  3
 4       19  3
 5       37  5
 6       67  3
 7      131  3
 8      263  7  
 9      523 11  
10     1031  7  
11     2053  5  
12     4099  3  
13     8209 17  
14    16421 37  
15    32771  3  
16    65539  3  
17   131101 29  
18   262147  3  
19   524341 53  
20  1048583  7  
21  2097169 17  
22  4194371 67
23  8388619 11  
24 16777259 43  
25 33554473 41  
26 67108961 97
```

Proofs or counterexamples may be far away, but is something known about this topic?

Comment: This follows from [Shinzel's Hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H).  Indeed that hypothesis  would show that every even number can be written as the difference of two primes.  Of course, little is known by way of actual proofs of specific cases.

Comment: According to [this](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/conjectures/) Chen's work on the Goldbach conjecture also implies that every (sufficiently large?) even number is the difference between a prime and a $P_2$ (a product of two primes).

Comment: This is a special case of an open problem,that every even number can be written as a difference of two primes.I believe it is true,but it seems to be an extremely difficult problem.

Comment: Some more terms at [OEIS A056206](https://oeis.org/A056206).

Comment: This is a great question.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: Do you suggest there are patterns or that I should present the examples better?

Comment: Green  and Tao say that there are infinitely many arithmetic progressions of arbitrary length $k$ of prime numbers. If we take some prime $p$ and look at a progression of period $2^m$, then there *should* be a progression of length $2^n$ such that $p+2^{m+n}=q$, $q$ being prime. Not quite a proof because Green and Tao don't say that arbitrarily long progression can have any chosen period. But since primes have the form $4j \pm 1$, a period of $2^n$ is not an unreasonable expectation. But not, as  I said, a proof.