# For all $n>1$ there are positive $a+b=n$ such that $a+ab+b\in\mathbb P$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, intuition, conjectures

For all integers $n>1$ there are positive integers $a,b$ such that $a+b=n$ and such that $a+ab+b\in\mathbb P$.
Tested for all $n\leq 1,000,000$. Hopefully, someone can explore and explain the heuristics about this conjecture.

---

This question is related to:
[Any odd number is of form $a+b$ where $a^2+b^2$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386860/any-odd-number-is-of-form-ab-where-a2b2-is-prime?rq=1)
[Does every power of two arise as the difference of two primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861380/does-every-power-of-two-arise-as-the-difference-of-two-primes)
[Most even numbers is a sum $a+b+c+d$ where $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399035/most-even-numbers-is-a-sum-abcd-where-a2b2c2-d2)
[Natural numbers large enough can be written as $ab+ac+bc$ for some $a,b,c>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373650/natural-numbers-large-enough-can-be-written-as-abacbc-for-some-a-b-c0)
[$\{a+b|a,b\in\mathbb N^+\wedge ma^2+nb^2\in\mathbb P\}=\{k>1|\gcd(k,m+n)=1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411538/aba-b-in-mathbb-n-wedge-ma2nb2-in-mathbb-p-k1-gcdk-mn-1)
[Even numbers has the form $a+b$ where $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410720/even-numbers-has-the-form-ab-where-fraca2b22-is-prime)
[Is every positive integer greater than $2$ the sum of a prime and two squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872973/is-every-positive-integer-greater-than-2-the-sum-of-a-prime-and-two-squares)

It's about a relation $R\subseteq \mathbb N^m$, a function 
$f:\mathbb N^m\to \mathbb N$, and an image of a restriction
$\operatorname{Im}(f|R)$.
In Goldbachs conjecture the relation is $p,q\in\mathbb P$, the function is $(p,q)\mapsto p+q$ and the image of the restriction is 
$2\mathbb N\setminus\{2\}$.

Maybe some of the conjectures can be generalized?

Comment: Equivalently, you conjecture that for every positive integer $n>1$ there exists a positive integer $a<n$ such that
$$a+a(n-a)+(n-a)=-a^2+na+n,$$
is prime.

Comment: If we put it in other terms you are claimin for all $n$ there is a prime equal go $n + (n-a)a$ for some $a$.

Comment: Calling $A=a+1$, and $B=b+1$, this is equivalent on saying that for all $N$ there exist positive integers $A,B \ge 2$ such that $A+B=N$, and $AB-1$ is prime.

Comment: Where did this conjecture come from? What is special about the expression $a+ab+b$?

Answer (score 1):

**This is only a partial answer.** Reformulating according to the comment of Crostul, we want to find $AB-1 \in \mathbb P$. Other than the even prime $2$, all primes are odd, so at least one of $A,B$ must be even. For $A+B=N,\ N\ge 6$, any prime generated will have the form $6m\pm 1$. So it is necessary (but not sufficient) that for every $N$, there are some $A,B$ such that $AB-1=6m\pm 1$ for the conjecture to be true.

$AB-1=6m\pm 1\Rightarrow AB\equiv (0,2) \mod{6}$. Any $N\ge 6$ can be split into two addends with that property. The following table lists values of residues $\mod{6}$ for $N,A,B$ that satisfy $N=A+B\mod{6}$ and $AB\equiv (0,2) \mod{6}$ (up to the order of $A,B$).

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\ N&A&B \\
0&0&0 \\
&2&4 \\ \\
1&0&1 \\
&3&4 \\ \\
2&0&2 \\
3&0&3 \\
&1&2 \\
&4&5 \\ \\
4&0&4 \\
5&0&5 \\
&2&3 \\
\end{array}$$

This shows that any $N$ can be split into addends $A,B$ such that $AB\equiv (0,2) \mod{6}$. In every case, it is possible to obtain addends such that $AB\equiv 0 \mod{6}$. Interestingly, only for $N\equiv (0,3)\mod6 \Rightarrow N\equiv 0 \mod3$ is it possible to obtain addends such that $AB\equiv 2 \mod{6}$. This means that $AB-1$ can generate numbers of the form $6m-1$ from any $N$, but can generate numbers of the form $6m+1$ only if $N\equiv 0\mod3$. It remains open at this point whether the numbers of the form $6m\pm 1$ obtained from a particular $N$ will necessarily feature a prime.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Let $$a+b+ab =p\in \mathbb{P}$$

then $$n = {a^2+p\over a+1}= a-1+{p+1\over a+1}$$

So if we take such $p$ and $a$ that $a+1\mid p+1$ and $a<n$ then $b={p-a\over a+1}$.

---

Question here is if such $p$ and $a$ alway exist.

Comment: Nice idea, but far from an answer. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: -1 This is a comment, not an answer.